# How do you include Azure Search's @search.score as part of your custom $orderby clause

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

According to [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-api-2015-02-28-preview), the default sort of Azure Search results is by Azure's own score (descending).  However, you can supply an $orderby clause, which is defined as:

> A list of comma-separated expressions to sort the results by. Each
>   expression can be either a field name or a call to the geo.distance()
>   function.

I want to sort by Azure's @search.score desc, MyFieldOne, MyFieldTwo.  But, I cannot figure out how to reference the @search.score "field."

I've tried the following:

```
$orderby=search.score+desc,MyFieldOne,MyFieldTwo
$orderby=@search.score+desc,MyFieldOne,MyFieldTwo
$orderby=%40search.score+desc,MyFieldOne,MyFieldTwo
```

These all result in http 502 or 400s.

How do I reference the @search.score value in my request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited**

Azure Search now supports sorting by score using the new `search.score()` OData function. For example, to sort by score then by name, do this:

`$orderby=search.score() desc, name asc`

The [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#order-by-syntax) has been updated to include the new `search.score()` function.

**Original answer:**

Azure Search currently doesn't let you refer to the score in an `orderby` clause. Please vote for this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328693-sort-results-by-rank) to help us prioritize this work.

Note, however, that score will rarely be the same for two documents, so using tie-breakers after the `$oderby=@search.score` will rarely come into play, and in most cases the sort order will be equivalent to sorting by rank, which is what happens by default.

Comment: my index has a lot of what might seem light repetitive data.  example, an index with 1000 items that have the text of 'sunset', where the image field refers to might be a user uploaded sunset photo that we have a path to.  if we search for 'sunset,' they all come back with the same score.  since I'm providing a paged result set, I need to further qualify the sort with my own fields that provide a deterministic result, so that paging will allow me to page through all the results.  I can't do it now.  Many results on page 1 show on page 2-n without allowing me to get through all results.