# Azure Search, filter by score

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to omit results with lower relevance.

Can do the filtering by myself, but I don't find any documentation on the scoring range.

for example, 
searching: "Sun protection", 
I would like to recive all results with "Sun protection" 
but not results with "sun light" or "snake protection"

I see a score from 0.8 would be good in that case, but is this persistent ?
One criteria is to filter every result that have only one from the search term.

(Top parameter will not help beacuase it mate be 50 relevance results or 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a look at these questions:

[azure search sort and filter by score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359236/azure-search-sort-and-filter-by-score)

[How do you include Azure Search's @search.score as part of your custom $orderby clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233008/how-do-you-include-azure-searchs-search-score-as-part-of-your-custom-orderby/34234258#34234258)

In general, document score reflects relative relevance of documents in a results set. It's not normalized so you can't compare it between different queries and there is no good threshold value you could use.

In your example you could issue a phrase query: "sun protection" to make the entire phrase match or search for: sun+protection (sun AND protection) to make sure both terms match. We offer two different query formats, to learn more go to [Simple query language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798920.aspx) and [Lucene query language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589323.aspx).

Let me know if that helps,

[Janusz](https://twitter.com/yahnoosh)

Comment: The second part does give me a solution, though the first part is not relevant since I didn't ask to compare between the results of different queries, only between the results of the one and only search query. And maybe you can supply some information on the range of values Score is limited to and the default Liner Interpolations effect on the score. @Yahnoosh

Comment: There is no defined range for the value of the score, that's why you can't pick a threshold safely.